# How to create a "global" WebMethod using Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, webmethod

I have a WebMethod that I use on a number of pages in my ASP.NET site.  I would like to move the function out of the individual pages and just have them reference a "global" WebMethod function.  I've done this with numerous "normal" static functions that I use throughout the site by just creating a class and placing them in there.  But this approach doesn't seem to work with a WebMethod function.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using a generic HTTP handler and calling that? How you use a generic handler is different to how you use a web method so this may not work for you, but if you could briefly explain what you are trying to do I could answer if a handler would be the way to go.

Comment: I'm trying to capture user input on several forms using AJAX rather than using an event that requires a page load.  The setup on each page is very similar, so the WebMethod can be generalized to work for all of them.  I am not familiar with the method you're talking about though.  How would that work?

Comment: You need to use webservice for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Attaching the WebMethod attribute to a Public method indicates that you want the method exposed as part of the **XML Web service**

If I get it right, this is not what you want to do, as this practice is oriented in exposing the functionality to outside consumers.

I would suggest three ways to avoid repeating the common functionality in ASP.NET.

The first way would be to use **page inheritance**. In ASP.NET a page a subclass of class [`System.Web.UI.Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Therefore, you could create a `BasePage` having all the common functionality, and your pages could inherit it, inheritting the respective functionality.

The second way, would be to use the [**decorator design pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). This design pattern would allow you to move common functionality in one place and decorating specific pages with it. It is not the simplest thing to do and therefore it would not be my first suggestion.

The third way is using an **HTTPHandler**. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) MSDN posts could help you understand what we are talking about. [This microsoft tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307997) could guide you on how to do it.

Hope I helped!

Comment: I think your first method will fit best.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

here you go:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb532367(v=vs.90).aspx

Walkthrough: Creating and Using AJAX-Enabled Web Service